# How to manage what roles that are authorized to access a controller?

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-identity, owin, claims-based-identity

The most straightforward way to add authorization of which role that's going to be accessing a controller method is the following one.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }
```

Of course, it's a pain in the rectal area to attribute every method by that, so any programmer who want to retain their sanity adds the filter as follows.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{ ... filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute()); }
```

Now, the problem is that when a user is authorized but has no roles claimed, they still can access the methods, which forces me to use the following syntax for every method anyway. That makes me sad.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "monkey,donkey")]
public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }
```

What I'd like to know is a way of adding such a global filter but only allowing for certain roles. The best approach I've found this far is to specify a property of the filter (a sneaky one, because it's got nothing about that in the constructor list), as follows.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{ ... filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute { Roles = "monkey,donkey" }); }
```

1. Is this a recommended way or is there's a more reliable approach?
2. How do I control if I only want to add the filter to certain methods/controllers?
3. How can I allow anonymous access to certain methods/controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way of doing things is to have a `BaseController` that looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
}
```

And then every other controller in your project should inherit from this controller. I usually have some helper methods inside of base controller.

For areas where only specific roles should have access I do a specific controller:

```
[Authorize(Role = "monkey")]
public class MonkeyController : BaseController
{
}
```

and then every controller with these permission inherits from `MonkeyController`.

And for anonymous access use `[AllowAnonymous]` on controllers or actions.

Comment: I curious where you place the file with the base controller. Is it placed together with the other controllers in the same folder or do you put it elsewhere. Good to know how others organize the files.

Comment: Yes,  usually I have base controller in the same folder as other controllers